# mongodump "Failed: bad option: can only dump a single collection to stdout"

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

```
mongodump --out "-"
```

doesn't work, it gives me this message : "Failed: bad option: can only dump a single collection to stdout".
What happens ?...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so the exception is self-explanatory that if you use --out "-" it can show only single collection on stdout.

So i would like to know as to what you want to achieve?

if you want to stdout a particular collection command is :

```
mongodump -o - -d <dbname> -c <collection name>
```

if you want to take dump of whole mongodatabase ideal command is:

```
mongodump --gzip --archive=db.tar
```

Comment: Thanks, it's also possible to dump all in a directory path, example : mongodump -o D:\database\dumps

Comment: yup. but i usually have practice to archive and gzip to use less space. in mongorestore you may restore with "mongorestore --gzip --drop --archive=db.tar" PS you may provide full path to archive as well

Answer (score 2):

Too dump a complete database to stdout you can use the `--archive` option (without parameter):

```sh
mongodump -d <dbname> --archive
```

Docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--archive